# Nested NSURLSessionDataTask on background thread

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsurlsession

My Code works just fine. What I need help, or clarification on is Nested `NSURLSessionDataTask` instances.
I'm making two asynchronously calls, the second call is dependent on the first.

So I make the first `NSURLSessionDataTask` (`firstUrlCall`) call which returns an array of objects. For each object in my array I then call the second `NSURLSessionDataTask` (`secondUrlCall`) and pass in a `dataID`.

As I mentioned before, it works. I just see alot of lines repeated and **REPEATED CODE IS NOT SEXY!!!**
So is there anything I can do to prevent this catastrophe? I need my code to be **SEXY!**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURLSession *Session;
```

**FIRST CALL**

```
-(void) firstUrlCall {

NSString *urlString = @"https://api.FIRSTURLCALL.com";

NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session
    dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]
        completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
              if (!error) {

                  NSDictionary *returnData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                  options:0
                                                                    error:nil];

                [returnData enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id dataID, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
                      /*
                        -->here is where I call secondUrlCall<--
                      */
                      [self secondUrlCall:dataID]; 

                  }];
              }
          });
        }];
 [dataTask resume];
}
```

**SECOND CALL**

```
-(void) secondUrlCall:(NSString *)dataID {

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.SECONDURLCALL.com?dataID=%@",dataID];
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session
                                  dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]
                                  completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                          if (!error) {
                                              NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                                              options:0
                                                                                                error:nil];
                                              if ([[json objectForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"sexy"]) {

                                                  [tableArray addObject:json];

                                                  // Reload table data
                                                  [self.tableView reloadData];
                                              }

                                          }
                                      });
                                  }];
[dataTask resume];
}
```

PS: Sorry if you were offended from my extensive use of the word **SEXY** :)

Comment: I don't think there is much wrong with the code; blocks make it difficult to re-use code without complicating it a fair bit.

Comment: @trojanfoe Thats what I was afraid of. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh my goodness! What if the network is intermittent or goes down half way through?

I would take the results of the first call and put each one into an operation queue, then when processing each operation if it fails you can re-queue it.

Comment: I actually implemented something a bit different but I will incorporate what you said. I didn't even take that into consideration. Thanks!